# 18.04 Remove spurious boot choice from boot menu

Tags: boot, bios

I'm working with a cast-off Intel server, and when I go to the Boot Menu after POST, there's an entry there BOOT0006. It does not appear in the BIOS/Settings which I access with <kbd>F2</kbd>.

How do I remove that bogus entry?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the internal drive (HDD or SSD).

Boot from a LiveUSB and open a terminal.

Run `sudo efibootmgr`; [efibootmgr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/efibootmgr.8.html) will show a list of all the boot devices stored in EFI, and their current order in booting.  Find the bogus entry to delete from that list and its order number.

Run `efibootmgr -b X -B` where X is the number of the bogus device to delete. For example, if BOOT0006 was the third item in the Boot Order, found in the previous step, do `efibootmgr -b 3 -B`.

Shut down, reboot to see the boot order; the bogus entry should be gone. Then you can reinstall the HDD or SDD.

Comment: Where in the process is the internal drive replaced?

Comment: @Organic Marble, good catch. Add that in last sentence of last graf.